# how can i show separate view for separate term for a single id?

Tags: php, mysql

View should be following:

```
Term 1
Result of term 1
Other activities of term 1

Term 2
Result of term 2
Other activities of term 2

Term3
Result of term 3
Other activities of term 3
```

But my code is showing the following view:

```
Term 1
Term 2
Term 3

Result of term 2
Result of term 2
Result of term 2

Other activities of term 1
Other activities of term 2
Other activities of term 3
```

i want to show the data 'term' wise....

here is my code.....

```
<?php   
include_once('config.php'); 

$cls = $_SESSION['cls'];
$student_id = $_SESSION['student_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * from class_6 WHERE  class_name='$cls' AND student_id='$student_id'";

$retval = mysql_query($sql,$connection);
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<b>Term</b> : {$row['term']}<br>";
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['bangla1']}</td>".
             "<td>{$row['bangla1_om']}</td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla1_hm']}</td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla1_tm']}</td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla1_grade']}</td></tr>".

         "<tr><td>{$row['bangla2']}</td> ".
         "<td>{$row['bangla2_om']} </td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla2_hm']} </td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla2_tm']} </td>".
         "<td>{$row['bangla2_grade']} </td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Term-Result-Other group in the cycle all together. It's hard to follow what should go in the view, as there is no DB structure to compare.

Also I'd strongly advise you start using PDO or whatever ORM, which will secure your database requests.

In your particular example:

```
while(<your-results>) {
    echo "Term: " . $row['term'];
    echo "Result:" . <whatever-row-fields>;
    echo "Other activities:" . <again-whatever-rows>
}
```